# Swift parsing a http request returns domain error

Tags: swift, http, post, swift3

okay, so Im trying to make a post request but when I try to parse the data, I always get a error domain code= 3840.
https://www.codepunker.com/tools/http-requests/64243-brrjq9t
In this example it shows what the request response looks like.
and this is my code:

```
let parameters =  ["txt": "כאב גרון","usr": "","pass": "" ,"ktivmale": false] as [String : Any]
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.nakdan.com/GetResult.aspx") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data,response, error in

        print(response!)
        if error != nil{
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                print(json)
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            })
        } catch {
            print(error)
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Connection Failed.")

        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: From your link, the response is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Game><Result>##שם זיהוי או סיסמה לא נכונים</Result></Game>` This is XML, not JSON. So it's normal that `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)` fails and throws that error.

Comment: so how can I do that?

Comment: Either you server allow with some param or header to responds in JSON and you just have to fix that part, or you need to parse XML (with XMLParser for example, or any lib doing it). It's two completely different parsing. Search about it ;)

Comment: I haven't found anything that works for me.. can you give me an example?